# setting up cake on hostgator

Tags: web-hosting, cakephp, server-settings

So i have been reading forum after forum and my bakery is still not functional.
Here is my folder tree:
/home/jja/public_html/
there i have: app, cake, index.php and one .htaccess that looks like:

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]

RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

I get no log errors and a 404 Error.

Answer (score 1):

This article might help you
[Installing CakePHP on shared hosting](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/installing-cakephp-on-shared-hosting)

I am also hosting my website on hostgator without any problems.
Dont keep your app and cake folders in public_html folder.

Move the app and cake folder to the main root i.e /home/username

Move all the folders inside the webroot to public_html

Your folder structure should look like this:

```
/home/username
  /app
  /cake
  /public_html
      /css
      /img
      /js
      index.php
```

You will also have to make changes to the index.php file found in the webroot. This has been explained in the above mentioned link.